# MD5 шифрование паролей.

Tags: php

Подскажите, если взять md5-хэш от суммы md5-хешей каждого символа слова, долго будет высчитвать? Длина слова не более 16 символов.

Comment: Нехорошо считать MD5-хэш от одного символа.

Comment: Почему?

Comment: Если это что-то связанное с безопасностью, лучше несколько раз 

`md5(sha1(md5($pass)))`

PS: если пробьют первый md5, второй пробьют через полчаса вручную (для букв очень просто сделать базу).

Comment: Потому что MD5 оперирует блоками по 16 байт, один символ он добьет 15-ю нулями. получается всего 256 разных значений хэша. поэтому ваша конструкция сможет породить всего 256^16 значений

Comment: Предлагаю вместо 16 отдельных символов считать хэши от 16 циклических сдвигов слова.

Comment: Мне нравится.

Comment: Во первых не шифрование а Хэширование. Во вторых зачем такое нужно непонятно.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, так проверьте. Сделайте массив со словами, допустим, 10 штук. Напишите функцию шифрования, поставьте ее выполнение в цикл, хотя бы тысяч 10 раз и замерьте таймером, потом среднеарифметическое высчитать не трудно. А так вряд ли кто скажет, ведь зависит в большей степени от загрузки сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, как на PHP, а у меня в программе шифрования на C разница между шифрованием с вычислением нового MD5 для каждых 16 входных символов с простым наложением однажды вычисленного MD5 (от ключа) была примерно на порядок. Простой вариант на примерно 100MB файле около 5MB/sec.

Если же у Вас задача онлайн регистрации пользователей, то я думаю, какие бы сложные вычисления Вы не проводили, на глаз это будет не заметно.

Answer (score 1):

Считать будет быстро. Поэтому MD5 (но не только) и **не** рекомендуется использовать для хэширования паролей.

Хэш-функция здесь используется для того, чтобы было сложно, зная хэш, узнать пароль. Даже для идеальной хэш-функции — чем она быстрее, тем проще перебирать пароли «грубой силой». Легитимные проверки паролей же занимают незначительную долю времени. Соответственно, используемая односторонняя функция должна быть медленной. Не настолько, конечно, медленной, чтобы проверка пароля «тормозила», но настолько, чтобы перебор «в лоб» был малоприятной затеей, а на типично доступном железе — бесперспективной.

См. http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Answer (score 0):

Создайте у себя на сайте файл: md5.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
      if (!empty($_POST['text'])) {
          $text = md5 /* md5(md5 или sha или хоть чо несколько раз)) */ ($_POST['text']);
          echo "$text";
      } else {
          echo "<form action="md5.php" method="post">n <input name="text" maxlengh="140"/>n<input type="submit"/></form>";
      }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

и на нем проверяйте!

ps простой хэш (то, что выше без `/*комментирования*/` написано), можете на моем сайте опробовать.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте salt: `md5($pass.'salt')`, salt - любое, известное только вам, слово.

Comment: Маленькое замечание: соль известна всем. И использование ее несколько другое:

    'salt'.md5($pass.'salt');

Эту операцию можно проделывать много раз:

    'salt'.md5('salt'.md5('salt'.md5($pass.'salt')));

Вот пароль - да, известен только юзеру.
Вся соль *смайл* в том, что это защита от подбора пароля при помощи радужных страниц. И с этой задачей она чудесно справляется.

Comment: Если нужна паранойя - используйте несколько алгоритмов хеширования в произвольном порядке например sha(md5().crc32())

Comment: Не надо использовать `H(message || key)`. Для этого есть [HMAC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). В похапе: [`hash_hmac`](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-hmac.php)`('md5', $pass, $salt);`

Comment: Если следовать вашей логике, выражение sha(md5().'1') снижает энтропию вообще к 2^0, если единичка - константа.

Comment: Да, я ошибся, прошу прощения, мне там приглючился вызов метода.